# Gitlab: Problems running Unicorn, Resque with Passenger/Nginx

Tags: nginx, passenger, resque, unicorn, gitlab

I have installed a Gitlab on a brand new Ubuntu (10.04) and it is working almost correctly. Gitlab is reachable on HTTP, I can push/pull data via git to the server. There is one thing missing though, the activity feed is not updating. So I thought there is something wrong with the git hooks. I completely followed the installation process from [Gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) except I'd like to use Passenger to run Nginx in order to deploy multiple apps.

I was running the the `sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production` to see if everything is set up correctly, but it said, `Redis` is not running. `ps aux` says, `redis-server` is up. So it is not the git hooks. Gitlab docu says, restart the gitlab service to solve that problem. In this case I get an error which I think is the problem I need to solve:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/gitlab restart
Error, unicorn not running!
```

My question is, how can I get around this problem? How can I run unicorn, I thought the gitlab service would start it? Am I not using Nginx? Before I start reinstalling the whole thing firstly without using Passenger, I thought I might ask the question here beforehand.

Comment: What do the unicorn log contain? Look for any log files for more information as to what blocks the start of gitlab (and redis in particular)

Comment: Well, the redis log does not say anything spectecular.. The Unicorn log had its last log entry a couple days back and says, it couldn't connect to the MySQL DB through the socket.. It is running, Gitlab uses properly.. Maybe I am missing a config somewhere? The unicorn config has nothing special to offer...

Comment: Then, if those logs aren't updated, it os on the nginx side that it doesn't work. Any log on that side?

Comment: Same mysql errors, but a couple days ago.. this can be ok because I forgot to start mysql in the first place..

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. I figured out, that my nginx and mysql services did not start yet after a reboot of my server, but gitlab services did. As soon as I started nginx or mysql manually, the gitlab processes died. I couldn't find out why though.

Comment: The order of starting those services might be important. I start mysql first, then nginx, then gitlab. For GitLab, I use a similar script than in their website: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitlab/gitlabd

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171465/gitlab-problems-running-unicorn-resque-with-passenger-nginx#comment19642379_14171465) by the [OP pabera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1062438/pabera), `nginx` and `mysql` must be started, for the other components of GitLab (`redis`, `unicorn`, and now `sidekiq`) to run properly.

The official [`/etc/init.d/gitlab` is here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/init.d/gitlab).

I have my [own version of `gitlabd` (here)](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitlab/gitlabd), because I manage [`sidekiq` in my own script](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitlab/sidekiqd), and I don't need to run the script as `root`.

You can see the run order for all the services [in this script](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/sbin/demod):

- ssh
- Apache and/or NGiNX
- mysql
- redis
- GitLab (which will start unicorn and sidekiq)

Comment: /gitlab/github: No such file or directory
Error, unicorn not running!

Comment: @FDisk not sure what you mean here. my script is based on a clone of gitlab, made in `$HOME/gitlab/github`, except it uses a special value for HOME: `$H` (which should be empty for you). It is not meant to be used directly, unless you build the all environment with `make_env.sh` (the goal being to compile everything needed for git/GitLab, in a user directory of his/her choosing, hence the `$H` representing that directory)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a poke in the dark...

In the GitLab installation.md README is states:

**"**

Start your GitLab instance:

```
sudo service gitlab start
# or
sudo /etc/init.d/gitlab restart
```

**"**

I did the first AND the second and got this exact error. However, I skipped the "or" and continued to the Nginx commands and it seems to work.

Hope this helps!